# assign a retrievable unique ID to a changing lambda list in python?

Tags: python, lambda, uniqueidentifier

```
def a(p): return p + 1

def b(p): return p + 2

def c(p): return p + 3

l= [a,b,c]

import itertools
ll = itertools.combinations(l, 2)

[x for x in ll]
[(<function a at 0x00CBD770>, <function b at 0x00CBD7F0>),
 (<function a at 0x00CBD770>, <function c at 0x00BB27F0>),
 (<function b at 0x00CBD7F0>, <function c at 0x00BB27F0>)]
```

**Q1:** here, how to return a lambda list in simple line(s):

```
[a(b(1)),  # not the result of a(b(1)), but just a lambda object
 a(c(1)),  # also items may more than 2 here if itertools.combinations(l, 4)
 b(c(1))]
```

**Q2:**

suppose I defined another function d

```
def d(p): return p + 4

l= [a,b,c,d]
ll = itertools.combinations(l, 2)

[(<function a at 0x00CBD770>, <function b at 0x00CBD7F0>),
 (<function a at 0x00CBD770>, <function c at 0x00BB27F0>),
 (<function a at 0x00CBD770>, <function d at 0x00CBDC70>),
 (<function b at 0x00CBD7F0>, <function c at 0x00BB27F0>),
 (<function b at 0x00CBD7F0>, <function d at 0x00CBDC70>),
 (<function c at 0x00BB27F0>, <function d at 0x00CBDC70>)]
```

this combination with different a sequence compare with last one :

```
ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd
=================
ab,ac,bc
```

But I want to keep all possible item with an unque ID, it means no matter how the

```
l= [a,b,c,d]
```

or

```
l= [b,a,c,d]
```

pr

```
l= [a,b,e,d]
```

Take **"ac"** for example: the **"ac"** and other possible item always with an unique ID bind then I can access **"ac"** with that unique ID. I think it is like to create an extendable hash table for each item.

So, is it possible to assign an int ID or a "HASH" to the lambda item? I also want this mapping relationship should be able to store in disk as a file and can be retrieved later.

Thanks for any idea.

sample to explain Q2

```
=====================
l= [a,b,c,d] 
func_combos = itertools.combinations(l, 2)
compositions = [compose(f1, f2) for f1, f2 in func_combos] 

[compositions[x](100) for x in compositions]  # take very long time to finish
[result1,
 result2,
 result3,
 ... 
 ]

======== three days later on another machine ======
l= [a,c,b,e,f,g,h] 
[compositions[x](100) for x in compositions] # take very long time to finish

[newresult1,
 newresult2,
 newresult3,
 ... 
 ]

but wait: here we can saving time: take "ac" for example:

[result1, tag
 result2, tag_for_ac_aka_uniqueID_or_hash
 result3, tag
 ... 
 ]

we just need to check if the "ac" tag exists we can reduce the calculation:
if hash_of(ac) in list(result.taglist):
   copy result to new result:
```

Comment: I think that what you are doing is non-trivial. It sounds like you are trying to save the results of the applying list of compositions to an object and use them later. This is called 'memoization'. It's easy. The twist is that you want to be able to accomplish it across a network so that makes it non-trivial. There is probably a library that will do this but I don't know of one.

Comment: thanks, memoization may not fit for my case, because the "result" here may goes to huge, so, just store them in pickle or alike is not suitable for non-trivial. And, to assign the unique id or the hash may get another advantage: on the low cpu speed machine, I can reuse the result calculated before reduce the cpu use, and on faster machine, I can use the "hash for lambda" to saving the huge result data transport - I just recalculate them because the machine is fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `set` to avoid dicts?

They are works for me.

Comment: `set()`. Dict are complex there.